# Is there a way to sort so that "Vitamin B12" is not in front of "Vitamin B6"?

Tags: ruby, sorting, natural-sort

In Ruby on Rails, the default sort order will be

```
Vitamin A
Vitamin B12
Vitamin B6
```

Is there a mechanism or quick way so that it will sort by a natural language way so that `B6` shows before `B12`?

Comment: See also @sethbc [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127913/sorting-strings-is-much-harder-than-you-thought/128026#128026) on this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
class Array
  def smart_sort
    sort_by{|s| (' '+s).scan(/(\d+)|(\D+)/).map{|d, s| s || d.to_i}}
  end
end

a = ['Vitamin A', 'Vitamin B12', 'Vitamin B6']
p a.smart_sort

# => ["Vitamin A", "Vitamin B6", "Vitamin B12"]
```

It sorts alternatively by digits and by non-digits.

```
b = ['3c17d', '1a34be',  '3x1a', '1b01c', '1a34bb']
p b.smart_sort

# => ["1a34bb", "1a34be", "1b01c", "3c17d", "3x1a"]
```

This is probably similar to what is done in Windows when sorting the file names within a directory.

---

Update: A newer version. Doesn't need `' '+`, as it is automatically supplied by `split`. It also removes the redundancy of specifying the complementary `\d` and `\D` in the regex.

```
class Array
  def smart_sort
    sort_by{|s| s.split(/(\d+)/).each_slice(2).flat_map{|s, d| [s, d.to_i]}}
  end
end
```

Comment: you convert the string into array... that's smart.  how come you add the `' '` to `s` at first?  in `(' '+s)`

Comment: That's because when you have an array that is a mix of strings that starts with a digit, and non-digit, like `%w[x12 x13 x1A x1B xAB 12x 13x 1A 1B]`, it will cause an error without `' '+` because integers will be compared with strings. This forces that it always starts with a non-digit, and does not cause an error.